# How to customize sorting in KendoGrid UI Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, customization

The data input to the kendo grid is:
 apple, bat, cat, dog, egg, fan

User entered 'egg' in the textbox, then output in the kendogrid should be like this. "egg" must be the topmost row and all other names should be displayed in alphabetical order.

```
    Name
   ==================
    "egg" 
    "apple" 
    "bat" 
    "cat" 
    "dog" 
    "fan"
```

Here is the code

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<input type="textbox" text="egg"/>
<script>

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({ dataSource: { data : [ { id: 1, name: "apple" }, { id: 2, name: "bat" }, { 
        id: 3, name: "cat" }, { id: 4, name: "dog" }, { id: 5, name: "egg" }, { id: 6, name: "fan" } ], 
       pageSize: 10, schema : { model: { fields: { id : { type: 'number' }, name: { type: 'string' } } } 
      } 
    }, editable : false, pageable : false, sortable : true, columns : [ { field: "id", title: "Number" }, 
     { field : "name", title : "Name", sortable: { compare: function (a, b) { return a.name == "e" ? "e" 
          :0 ; } } } ] }).data("kendoGrid");
</script>
```

Can some one please answer to the above question

Comment: Feel free to reference [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); Asking the right question correctly is sure to elicit more responses. It is often more helpful if you include at least a brief explanation along with your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The default sorting of the grid is done by clicking the header of the column. I assume that you want to implement some sort of a custom sorting which depends on user input.

You could customize the sort logic by passing a `compare` handler to the sort object.

e.g.

```js
      var numbers = {
        "one"  : 1,
        "two"  : 2,
        "three": 3,
        "four" : 4,
      };

      var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
          { id: 1, item: "two" },
          { id: 2, item: "one" },
          { id: 3, item: "three" },
          { id: 4, item: "four" }
        ]
      });

      dataSource.sort({ field: "item", dir: "asc", compare: function(a, b) {
           return numbers[a.item] - numbers[b.item];
            }
       })
```

In your case instead of using the `numbers` object in the compare handler, simply use the input of the user.